# How to distribute a lot of data with APK?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, installation, apk

I wish to pack a lot of data in my android package. May I use database for this? If yes, then how to pack database tables with APK?

Answer (score 1):

You may put your database in the `assets/` folder and when your application is run for the first time use the following code to copy your databases where they are supposed to be:

```
private void copyFromAssets() {
    InputStream istream = null;
    OutputStream ostream = null;
    try {
        istream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        File path = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        if (path.exists() == false)
            path.createNewFile();

        ostream = new FileOutputStream(path);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int length;
        while ((length = istream.read(buffer))>0) {
            ostream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        ostream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy database: " + DATABASE_NAME);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ostream != null) ostream.close();
            if (istream != null) istream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

After that you may use your database the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

To create the table you can use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` (ref [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and credit [there](http://people.bridgewater.edu/~arn002/csci440/android-tutorial.htm#database))

```
private class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public MyOpenHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
       // Replace this SQL code with the code for your database.
        String query = "CREATE TABLE people (" +
          "_id integer primary key autoincrement not null, " +
          "first_name text, last_name text);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
        // should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything
        // else it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.
    }
}
```

The table will be created or updated when accessed if needed.
You can also populate the database if needed after table creation.
You might want to provide a web-service to feed the initial data if it can help decreasing the size of the APK (and if size is your concern).

Comment: `onUpgrade` is / should be used if you want to change the tables / views / etc of your database in an upgraded version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Since APKs are still limited to 50MB you could try adding the database as an expansion file, separately from the application. Here are more details: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html

Comment: Did you try this? Would you still have to copy the DB from the directory of the expansion file to the database directory as mentioned by lenik, again doubling the space needed?